# Using annotation @Grab fails

Tags: java, maven, groovy

I follow the book **Groovy 2 Cookbook**, on the page 60 it states that to set an external dependency available in Maven Central Repository I can rely on `@Grab` annotation. Here's the code:

```
@Grab('org.apache.httpcomponents:httpclient:4.2.1')
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet 

def httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient() 
def url = 'http://www.google.com/search?q=Groovy'
def httpGet = new HttpGet(url) 

def httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet) 
new File('result.html').text = httpResponse.entity.content.text
```

The compiler issues an error on the first three lines:

```
unable to resolve a class org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient.
```

Is there a way to resolve this issue?

Comment: Your example works for me with Groovy 2.4.5. Is is possible that your computer is behind a proxy server? - http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/grape.html#Grape-Proxysettings

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Error grabbing Grapes ... unresolved dependency ... not found](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24873542/error-grabbing-grapes-unresolved-dependency-not-found)

Comment: Works for me too. How did you invoke the compiler?